# Greeter Resolution on Juno

Tags: release-juno, greeter, resolution

Has anyone managed to change the greeter resolution? Found solutions here involving lightdm configs but it was from 2015 and when i tried it didn't really change.
My session resolution is 1680*900 but native is 1920*1080 and the greeter defaults to that.

Answer (score 0):

First generate a "modeline" by using **cvt**

Syntax is: **cvt** width height refreshrate

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
```

this gives you:

```
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Now tell this to **xrandr**:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then you can now add it to the table of possible resolutions of an output of your choice:

```
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 1920x1080_60.00
```

You can find the Monitor name by:

```
# xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 1366/344x768/193+0+0  eDP-1
```

The changes are lost after reboot, to set up the resolution persistently, create the file `~/.xprofile` with the content:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 1920x1080_60.00
```

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

Comment: Thanks, but i'm trying to change the greeter resolution before login. the last step you gave is for after i'm logged into my session.